# What can cause drastic traffic jump on server?

Tags: linux, log-files, traffic

In the last couple of days, between 3AM and 4AM my server traffic jumps tenfold, from 20MB to 200MB.

[image]

I've checked the access log, and while there is significant googlebot activity, the difference is not so drastic in the mentioned period compared to other periods of the day. I couldn't find anything else in the access log that would indicate a problem.
I also checked sendmail log and nothing there either.

I will now sweep the access log for singular URLs that might have caused this, but in the mean time, were else can I check? What can I do to hunt this down?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I indeed have set up a cron that downloads my backups to a different server. Please add your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has all the hallmarks of a nightly backup.